# Equation with integral term under the rescaling $u_\lambda = \lambda u(\lambda^2 t, \lambda x)$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u(t,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u(t,x) \int_{-\infty}^x k(x-y)u(t,y) dy \right)$$
I want to study the equation that comes out of the following rescaling:
$$u_\lambda = \lambda u(\lambda^2 t, \lambda x), \qquad t >0, \ x \in \mathbb R.$$
What is the PDE for $u_\lambda$?
I guess/hope that it should be
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} u_\lambda(t,x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(u_\lambda(t,x) \lambda\int_{-\infty}^x k(\lambda(x-y))u_\lambda(t,y) dy \right)$$
but my computations are not adding up.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac{d}{dt}u_\lambda(t,x)=\lambda^3(\frac{d}{dt}u)(\lambda^2 t,\lambda x)$ and from the original equation we obtain $\frac{d}{dt}u_\lambda(t,x)=\lambda^3 (\frac{d}{dx}(u(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\lambda x} k(\lambda x-y)u(\lambda^2 t,y)dy=\lambda^3 (\frac{d}{dx}(u(\lambda^2t,\lambda x)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} k(\lambda (x-y))u(\lambda^2 t,\lambda z)\lambda dz=\lambda^2 ("\frac{d}{dx}"(u_\lambda(t,x)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} k(\lambda (x-y))u_\lambda(t,z) dz))$

You should now be aware that $\frac{d}{dx}$ means the variable $x$ and not $\lambda x$. For this we observe $\frac{d}{dx}\lambda u(\lambda^2 t,\lambda x)=\lambda^2\partial_2u(\lambda^2 t,\lambda x)=\lambda \partial_2 u_\lambda u(t,x)$

So we conclude now with correct terminology of $x$
$\frac{d}{dt}u_\lambda(t,x)=\lambda^3 (\frac{d}{dx}(u_\lambda(t,x)\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} k(\lambda (x-y))u_\lambda(t,z) dz))$

Comment: So you mean that I should replace the first $\lambda$ with $\lambda^3$ in my guess? Isn't it weird? What scaling should I perform to recover exactly my guess?

Comment: What is your goal? You have this $u_\lambda$ given and want to know the equation in terms of $u_\lambda$? Then my computation is probably correct (i may also miss an exponent). You can just plain and simple compute it. What you wrote down looks a bit like a naive guess, did somebody say that it is correct?